# How to Create Query Status Table Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am currently a user of a Postgres database (I am not the DBA). Within my sandbox I run several business critical scripts every day and currently track their status by first in a log text file on my desktop while running the scripts in a batch file. I am trying to create a table in my sandbox that can be used for reporting and analysis that includes the status of the scripts as well as if any of them have failed to run properly or not. 
Such as:

```
----------------------------------------+-----------
 Beginning Script-A                     | Timestamp
 Script-A Completed Successfully        | Timestamp
 Beginning Script-B                     | Timestamp
 Script-B failed to Run Successfully    | Timestamp
----------------------------------------+-----------
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You might get better responses on Stack Overflow as this is a general database issue. Roughly speaking you'd create a new table with a text column for the log message and a timestamp column with the default value `now()`, then do insert statements like `INSERT INTO my_table(log_column) VALUES('Starting Script A')` for logging.

Comment: I just did this myself--basically what Jason says but if its all within a transaction (as my mine are), you'll need to use `clock_timestamp()` because `now()` is the start time of the transaction.